# Разделение картинок, по 4 штуки на слайд

Tags: php

В хтмл должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
<div class="slide">                                 <div class="ph1"><img src="img/hotel/ph1.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="ph2"><img src="img/hotel/ph2.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="ph3"><img src="img/hotel/ph3.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="ph4"><img src="img/hotel/ph4.png" alt="" /></div>
</div>

<div class="slide">
<div class="ph1"><img src="img/hotel/ph1.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="ph2"><img src="img/hotel/ph2.png" alt="" /></div>   
<div class="ph3"><img src="img/hotel/ph3.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="ph4"><img src="img/hotel/ph4.png" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

В пхп я сделал так:

```
<?$countmorephoto = 1;?>
<?foreach ($arrayimg as $keyimg => $imgmore):?>
<?$keyimg++;?>
    <?if ($countmorephoto == 1){?>
        <div class="slide">
    <?}?>
    <div class="ph<?=$countmorephoto?>"><img src="<?=$imgmore?>" alt="" /></div>
    <?if ($countmorephoto == 4 || $countmorephoto == 8 || $countmorephoto == 12 || $countmorephoto == 16){?>
        <?$countmorephoto = 0;?>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
    <?}?>
<?if (!next($arrayimg)):?>  
        </div>
<?endif;?>
    <?$countmorephoto++;?>
<?endforeach;?>
```

Но работает честно говоря не очень :)

Как лучше разделять по 4 изображения, зная что их не может быть более 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы таки не поверите:

```
<?
$n = 0;
foreach ($arrayimg as $keyimg => $imgmore)
{
  $n++;
  if ($n % 4 == 1) { ?><div class="slide"><? }
  ?><div class="ph<?=$n?>"><img src="<?=$imgmore?>" alt="" /></div><?
  if ($n % 4 == 0) { ?></div><? }
}
if ($n % 4 > 0) { ?></div><? }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы всегда пишете новую строку заключая её в  <??> ?

Вам на [говнокод](http://www.govnokod.com), простите конечно.

```
<?$countmorephoto = 1;?>
<?foreach ($arrayimg as $keyimg => $imgmore):?>
<?$keyimg++;?>
    <?if ($countmorephoto == 1){?>
        <div class="slide">
    <?}?>
    <div class="ph<?=$countmorephoto?>"><img src="<?=$imgmore?>" alt="" /></div>
    <?if ($countmorephoto == 4 || $countmorephoto == 8 || $countmorephoto == 12 || $countmorephoto == 16){?>
        <?$countmorephoto = 0;?>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
    <?}?>
<?if (!next($arrayimg)):?>  
        </div>
<?endif;?>
    <?$countmorephoto++;?>
<?endforeach;?>
```

Comment: реально жесть)

Comment: А я о чем.

Comment: Не используйте в php 

     || // не делайте этого !11!АДИН
     
     // используйте
     
     or

Comment: а разница ? Ну приоритеты разные, но это должен знать каждый!

Comment: @shurik, так это самое же:

    if ($countmorephoto == 4 || $countmorephoto == 8 || $countmorephoto == 12 || $countmorephoto == 16)

    if ($countmorephoto == (4 || $countmorephoto) == (8 || $countmorephoto) == (12 || $countmorephoto) == 16)

У `==` приоритет 7, у `||` - 2. Поэтому либо в скобки, либо `OR`. Кстати, сам только недавно постиг эту штуку, писал все с огромным кол-вом скобок)